# PC stuck in BIOS with 4 TB harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, bios

So, I've got a pretty weird problem here.

I have a 4 TB harddrive which worked perfectly fine.
Today I bought an external case for it, inserted the drive and connected it.
Somehow it got repartitioned into 2 x 2 TB => Bad!
After googling I found out that the case does support 4 TB drives only by emulation, nice.

Now the 4 TB drive was messed up.
I used testdisk to rewrite the correct partition and rebooted.
And since then the PC doesn't boot up anymore, it's just stuck at BIOS.
Same problem in my other PC.
Now I can't even use any diagnostic tools... :(

What the hell is going on?

Comment: It sounds like you have not full reversed the damage the external case did.  I suggest delete the existing partitions and create a single partition.

Comment: @Ramhound, the problem is (I think) that they can't *get* the computer into a state where it can write to the disk safely.

Comment: Boot from the Windows install/recovery disc and use the recovery console command "fixmbr" and "fixboot"

Comment: @psusi: the 4TB drive is not the system drive

Comment: It sounds like your bios thinks otherwise.  Make sure it's set to boot from the other drive rather than trying the 4tb one first.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the 4TB harddrive, then reboot. (This may require finding a new harddrive to boot *from*.)

Comment: The 4TB drive is not the system drive, so I can boot when removing it. But how to edit the partitions when I can't boot when the drive is connected?

Comment: @Hype, ah, yes, I'm not actually sure whether it would be safe to plug it in when the computer is already running. (It *should* be fine, but risking damage to your computer on a 'should' is... no.) Maybe check the bios settings and see if the 4TB drive is on the list of bootable media? Both when it's unplugged and, if you can get to bios settings when it's plugged in. If so, set it to not bootable and/or remove it from the list. Similarly, look for anything else that looks like it might cause the bios to read from the 4TB disk.

Comment: I checked the BIOS but there's nothing which points to the 4TB disk, when it's not connected. I also tried resetting the BIOS through removing the battery, but this didn't help too :(

Comment: Well, if you can get to the bios settings when it is connected, that's a bit more likely to have it, but aside from that (and if you want risk it, plugging the drive in while the computer's running), I think you might need to find a meatspace tech support person.

Comment: So I tried to plug in the drive while being in Windows but I get a bluescreen after about 10-15 seconds :( Any other advice?

Comment: @Hype, well you might try linux, since it's a bit better stability wise, or try getting a new (different) external case, but if you could do that, you probably wouldn't be using the crappy one still.

Comment: That's odd... I've plugged in drives on the fly in linux and in windows back when I ran it.  Just had to force a scan for the disk to show up ( this was with ide disks, sata controllers now usually have hotplug support so they show up automatically ).

Comment: I tried it with linux. linux doesn't crash, but nothing happens. the harddrive runs, but it doesn't show up in gparted.

Comment: @Hype, try hitting ctrl-r? Not sure what else to suggest.